# What is a .net file in caffe?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, deep-learning, caffe

I want to reduce the size of my .caffemodel file.

I came across Deep Compression ([songhan/Deep-Compression-AlexNet](https://github.com/songhan/Deep-Compression-AlexNet)).

This creates a .net file. How do I use it for predictions? Or how to I convert it to a .caffemodel file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [Usage](https://github.com/songhan/Deep-Compression-AlexNet#usage) section in the git repository you are using:

> ```
> python decode.py bvlc_alexnet_deploy.prototxt AlexNet_compressed.net $CAFFE_ROOT/alexnet.caffemodel
> ```

Use the provided `decode.py` script to convert the compressed `'.net'` binary file to a usable `'.caffemodel'` you can use for deploying your net.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I misunderstood the usage. I thought it created a .net file from the .caffemodel file. How would I go about compressing CaffeNet? Any suggestions?

Comment: @VikramBajaj  : How to create binary .net file?